# Python: request.get multiple selectors syntax

Tags: python

In [the flight aware python example:](https://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/)

```
import requests

username = "YOUR_USERNAME"
apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY"
fxmlUrl = "https://flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML3/"

payload = {'airport_code':'KSFO', 'type':'enroute', 
    'howMany':'10'}
response = requests.get(fxmlUrl + "AirportBoards", 
    params=payload, auth=(username, apiKey))
```

If there were 3 desired airport selector codes: KFSO or KMIA or KMCO. How would this be specified?

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of multiple values in the [FlightXML3 docs](https://flightxml.flightaware.com/soap/FlightXML3/doc#op_AirportBoards) – it just says "airport code", singular.

Note that neither Python nor Requests understand "selectors" as such. Your example with `params=` is just syntax sugar, a convenient way to craft a HTTP query string which is then added to the URL (so your example is the same as `get("AirportBoards?airport_code=KSFO&type=enroute&…")`).

But how that query string is *interpreted* is entirely up to the web service. There is no standard syntax for more elaborate queries. Some services support multiple specifications of the same parameter (which you can pass as an array of values in Requests), or a single comma-separated value, or PHP-style "airport_code[]" parameter name – but it's not guaranteed that *any* of those methods is supported. So **read your web service's API documentation**.